# Spatial join and auto split segment

Tags: spatial-join

[image]
I am trying to join traffic counts to a roads layer. I have done this with a spatil Join but I have to manualy cut the road into segments before, so its 1 road segment joined to 1 traffic count.That way each road segment has a traffic count. I want to continue this but automate the cutting of road segments as I have over 100 traffic count locations. Qgis or ArcMap.

Comment: Which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop have you already used try and do this, and using that software what precisely did you try and where did you get stuck?  By asking about how to do something in either of or both products you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].